# How to format variable strings by alphabetical order using jidea?

Tags: java, string, intellij-idea, formatting, alphabetical

Is there a way to format(arrange) variable strings by alphabetical order using IntelliJ-Idea ?
Example Code:

```
public static final String c = "some_value";
public static final String a = "some_value";
public static final String b = "some_value";
```

After formatting it should appear as follows,

```
public static final String a = "some_value";
public static final String b = "some_value";
public static final String c = "some_value";
```

Please help on this.

Answer (score 3):

`Settings > Project Settings > Code Style > Java > Arrangement  ~ Matching Rules`. In there (each of the rules) you can choose to `order by name`. This should order them alphabetically as you requested. Though I don't know if you will need to change all of the matching rules.

Answer (score 1):

Goto `File`-->`Settings`--->`Code Style`(Select `Java` under it)--->`Arrangement`--->`Edit` `public static final` row--->Select `Order` as `order by name`.

Then Goto `Code`--->`Reformat Code`--->`Ticked the Reformat entries` from the pop up.-->`Run`

That is it.

[image]

[image]